# Dynamically add 5 minutes to TimeShift in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, groovy, jmeter, timeshift

I have created a loop in Jmeter and I have a counter within the loop.

```
vars.put("counter", "5")
```

I am then incrementing the loop by +5 for every iteration of the loop.  What I am trying to do is add that counter to this:

```
${__timeShift(HH:mm:ss,,PT5M,,)}
```

So I am trying to dynamically add 5 minutes to the TimeShift each iteration.  so something like ${__timeShift(HH:mm:ss,,PT${counter}M,,)}.  I know this is wrong but I can't think of a way to do it.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I know the counter I am using is a String.  I am converting it to an int and then trying to add the int into timeShift like: ${__timeShift(yyyyMMdd,,P${i}D,,outputDate)}

Answer (score 0):

This guy: `${__timeShift(HH:mm:ss,,PT${counter}M,,)}` should work just fine, most probably the problem is with the way you're incrementing the counter.

Instead of scripting you can consider switching to [Counter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter) configuration element:

[image]

So you would be able to get something like:

[image]

If you want to continue with scripting be aware of [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) function which allows you storing any arbitrary object into JMeter Variables so you won't have to convert it from String to Integer and vice versa